# Multiple group by Total in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I can fetch kind of data

- Tops

  - girl           5
  - boy           10
- Jean

  - girl           5
  - boys           15

Now I want to add one extra Total row in query output. Like

- Total

  - girl      10
  - boy       25

This is my query

```
    SELECT id, cloth_type, gender, qty, from
(SELECT 
    g.id as id,cloth.type as cloth_type, g.gender as gender, g.qty as qty
    0 AS sortorder -- added a sortorder column
       from
            cloth_master cloth
            inner join
            gender_master g on cloth.gender_id = g.id
            group by cloth.type, g.gender g.id
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
            g.id as id,cloth.type as cloth_type, g.gender as gender, g.qty as qty
            1 AS sortorder -- added a sortorder column
       from
            cloth_master cloth
            inner join
            gender_master g on cloth.gender_id = g.id
            group by cloth.type, g.gender g.id
) AS unionquery
) ORDER BY sortorderenter
```

I try with UNION ALL but not getting exact solution, can any one guide me for the same?

Comment: Please show the query that you are currently using.

Comment: And the table structure

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you can use grouping sets;

```
select coalesce(col1, 'Total'), col2, count(*)
from t
group by grouping sets ((col1, col2), (col1));
```

You can read about `GROUPING SETS` in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/queries-table-expressions.html).